# Java Netbeans Heap Size

Tags: java, netbeans, heap-memory

I have a Java project that needs a lot of memory to run. When I change the flags here:[image]

It works fine, however I still need a bigger Heap size but whenever I choose a bigger size like 2g or something like that it always shows the following message:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? And what can I do to correct this issue, I looked everywhere but can't seem to find a solution and I really need this for an assignment that is to be due sooner than I hoped...

EDIT: I should add that my computer has 8GB ram so that shouldn't be the issue and I'm working on Windows 10 if that matters.

EDIT1: When I click on help->about I get this window:

[image]

How can I conclude from here if my jvm is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Ditch NetBeans! Get Eclipse !

Comment: Won't I have to set the heap size there too?

Comment: Well probably you will have to (but its rather easy ;)). But on the other hand why do you need huge heap size - whats sort of application you are running ?

Comment: @sharp_c-tudent how much of that 8GB is actually available when you try to run your application ?

Comment: My app receives a file as input that contains millions of lines and needs to store data about each one, that's why I need so much space.

Comment: Sounds as if you are using a 32bit JVM. That is limited to about 1.5GB of heap. Install a 64bit JVM and you should be fine. No need to switch to another IDE

Comment: and how can I know how much of my 8GB are available to run my app?

Comment: task manager or what you call it in windows 10 should tell you that, if @a_horse_with_no_name didn't resolve your problem already.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was just making a point there that eclipse is the more or less standard tool everyone is using. NetBeans is not the best IDE out there lets face it. Also 32bit JVM allows actually 4GB in theory but actual size should be around 2GB so this should be enough

Comment: @MaciejCygan: Eclipse might have been a better IDE 10 years ago, but it sure is much better then Eclipse nowadays. And no, a 32bit process can **not** use 4GB on Windows. It's limited to 2GB process memory and in Java this means about 1.5GB heap space.

Comment: @zubergu: "Help -> About" from inside NetBeans will show what kind of JVM is being used

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually you are wrong here sir. a 32bit windows on x86 architecture is limited to 4GB of physical memory (although BIOS and GPU can reserve small chunk, therefore user can actually use about 3.3GB of RAM on a 32 bit architecture. 32Bit JVM uses the same principle - some processes can reserve the memory therefore usable space is about 2GB for a 32bit JVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How can I conclude from here if my jvm is 32 or 64 bit?*

You **are** using a 32bit JVM.

A 64bit JVM includes that information in the version string, e.g.:

```
1.8.0_92; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.92-b14
```

A 32bit process is restricted to 2GB of memory and with Java you usually can't usually use more then about 1.2GB. I think this depends on the Windows version and configuration.

[image]

So just remove the 32bit JDK and install the 64bit one, then you can use all the 8GB that your computer has.

Comment: 2GB?  That's not much really, (half of the total 4gb allowed on 32-bit machines) but I guess for the 32-bit Architecture it's enough.  Seeing as how 64-bit has been around for quite some time, it's pretty baffling that 32-bit OSes are still in use.

Comment: @Lasagna: in this case it's not a 32bit _OS_, but a 32bit _application_

Comment: Well, I figure the only reason to make a 32-bit application would be to run on a 32-bit machine... Unless there is some info I'm not aware of, but I'm always open to discussion :).

Comment: @Lasagna: I see a lot of people using 32bit applications on 64bit system. Most of the time because they just don't care (until they hit something like this)

Comment: I normally see older applications running in 32-bit, but some have both 32 and 64 executables.  I didn't think we could run a 32-bit version of the JDK/JRE in a 64-bit environment...  I thought Oracle discourages that, and that it wouldn't even work.